# how to use haml layout for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I found a layout at https://github.com/evenwu/pinterest-clone-layout that I would like to try. However, I have no idea how to integrate this with my existing rails project. My current layout looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"/>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I use the layout from the github link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `gem 'haml'` to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`.

Copy layout and stylesheets, etc. to your project.

Remember to remove your `.erb` layout; Rails gives `.erb` precedence over `.haml` by default.